# PWA not visible as a share option

Tags: javascript, android, manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I would like to allow users to share photos to my progressive web application.

I have followed [this](https://web.dev/web-share-target/#accepting-files) tutorial to achive it, but my pwa is still not visible as a share option.

Test device I use is android, I belive that my PWA meets all of [these](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners#criteria) conditions because I can successfully download it to my screen.

App itself, and all of it other features work fine when I download it to the screen, but I still can't get it to show as a share option.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name" : "appname",
    "short_name": "shortname",
    "theme_color": "#333333",
    "background_color": "#333333",
    "description": "app description",
    "start_url": "https://appHomeUrl.co",
    "display": "standalone",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "./assets/icons-192.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
      },
      {
        "src": "./assets/icons-512.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "512x512"
      }
    ],
    "share_target": {
      "action": "/photos/dosomething/1",
      "method": "POST",
      "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
      "params": {
        "title": "name",
        "text": "description",
        "url": "link",
        "files": [
          {
            "name": "myImage",
            "accept": ["image/jpeg", "image/png"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working, I think that there were 2 problems:

1. **Icons paths**

   ./assets/icons-192.png probably only works on the homepage, I changed it to

   /assets/icons-192.png
2. **Downloading the app to the screen at the wrong time**

   I register my service worker only after login (I should probably change that) so when I downloaded my pwa to the homescreen, I didn't have registered service worker yet so the app didn't meet the requirements to be shown as a share option